# Flatbuffer buffer is always empty

Tags: c#, flatbuffers

I have a schema:

```
namespace ExampleApp.Assets.Communications;

table FlatServerToClientMessage {
  messageid:string;
  imagebytes:[ubyte];
}

root_type FlatServerToClientMessage;
```

and for clarity, here is `ServerToClientMessage.cs`:

```
public class ServerToClientMessage : EventArgs
{
    public Guid MessageId { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageBytes { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to send, via TCP my `ServerToClientMessage`. This works fine when I use JSON, so it is not a problem somewhere else.

I have a `FlatSerialize` extension method which is supposed to serialize `ServerToClientMessage` and return a byte array. However, my `buffer.Data` is always empty... it is just full of zeros. My `ServerToClientMessage` does have data - it does have both a MessageId and ImageBytes.

Here is the serialize extension:

```
 public static byte[] FlatSerialize(this ServerToClientMessage message) {
   var builder = new FlatBufferBuilder(1);

   //Create an ID
   var MessageId = builder.CreateString(message.MessageId.ToString());

   //Start the vector...
   //Loop over each byte and add it - my god, is there not a better way?
   FlatServerToClientMessage.StartImagebytesVector(builder, message.ImageBytes.Length);
   foreach(var imageByte in message.ImageBytes) {
    builder.AddByte(imageByte);
   }
   var imagebytes = builder.EndVector();

   //Start the FlatServerToClientMessage and add the MessageId and imagebytes
   FlatServerToClientMessage.StartFlatServerToClientMessage(builder);
   FlatServerToClientMessage.AddMessageid(builder, MessageId);
   FlatServerToClientMessage.AddImagebytes(builder, imagebytes);

   //End the FlatServerToClientMessage and finish it...
   var flatMessage = FlatServerToClientMessage.EndFlatServerToClientMessage(builder);
   FlatServerToClientMessage.FinishFlatServerToClientMessageBuffer(builder, flatMessage);

   var buffer = builder.DataBuffer;
   return buffer.Data;
  }
```

Does anyone have any idea why my `buffer.Data` is just filled with zeros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your buffer isn't empty, it just doesn't start at offset 0 in `Data` (FlatBuffers are built back to front), it starts at `Offset`. You can access the bytes from there on. Alternatively, you can call `FlatBufferBuilder.SizedByteArray()` to create a byte array that has only the FlatBuffer data.

Comment: Thank you for your help!